# How to select names from one table having id's in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables `user_inform` and `company_info`.

Table `user_info`:

```
userid - username
1 ------------> a
2-------------> b
3-------------> c
```

Table `company_info`:

```
companyid -        companyname -        CreatedBy -    ModifiedBy
101 ------------> c1------------------->1---------------------->1
102-------------> c2------------------->2---------------------->3
103-------------> c3------------------->1---------------------->2
```

How can I get the names of user, i.e. username from table user_info in the place of CreatedBy and ModifiedBy in table company_info?

I.e.

```
companyid - companyname - CreatedBy - ModifiedBy
101---->    c1---->       a----->     a
102---->    c2---->       b----->     c
103---->    c3---->       a----->     b
```

I have tried this:

```
select A.companyid, A.companyname, B.username as CreatedBy, ModifiedBy
from company_info A
inner join user_inform B
    on (A.CreatedBy = B.userid)
```

Comment: At a glance, foreign keys and a join.....what have you tried?

Comment: @Tim, foreign keys are there for data consistency, don't really make a difference when select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` the user_info table twice. First time to get the created by user, second time to get the modified by user.

```
select ci.companyid, ci.companyname, uc.username CreatedBy, um.username ModifiedBy
from company_info ci
left join user_info uc on ci.CreatedBy = uc.userid
left join user_info um on ci.ModifiedBy = um.userid
```

(`LEFT JOIN` just in case one of the users are missing.)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN User_table T1 ON table1.CreatedBy = T1.userid
LEFT JOIN User_table T2 ON table1.ModifiedBy= T2.userid
```

Comment: Your join criteria looks a little....off....Not to mention the query is not going to produce the output OP is looking for.

Comment: @Mansoor its giving an error Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '**username**' to data type int

Comment: @Mansoor its not coming its still coming in int format itself

Comment: @Suhas,check your CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,userid fields data types.Is all are same data type ie INT..?

Answer (score 0):

Mansoor (above) is close:

```
SELECT
    c.companyid, c.companyname, u_c.username AS CreatedBy, u_m.username AS ModifiedBy
FROM 
    (company_info c INNER JOIN user_info u_c ON company_info.CreatedBy = u_c.userid)
    LEFT JOIN user_info u_m ON company_info.ModifiedBy = u_m.userid
```

Comment: its comming wrong i.e its showing **A** for every **ModifiedBy** and **CreatedBy**

Comment: Why one INNER JOIN and one LEFT JOIN? I'd chose the same type in both cases.

Comment: I did an INNER JOIN for CreatedBy because I assumed every record was created by someone. I did a LEFT JOIN for ModifiedBy because it's possible that a record was not modified by anybody, so it may be NULL.

I made one mistake -- forgot to give company_info the alias of "c". It's fixed above.